# How to mapping field from json to model field in drf serialiazer?

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have a model:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    genre_type_id = models.ForeignKey(GenreType)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    year = models.DateField()
```

and serializer:

```
class BookSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    model = Book
    fields = ('id', 'genre_type_id', 'author', 'year')
    read_only_fields = ('id', )
```

Server receives **POST** request with data:

```
{
    "genre": 1,
    "author": 3,
    "title": "My title",
    "year": "2016.01.01"
}
```

How to map **`genre`** field from json to **`genre_type_id`** model field in drf serializer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to explicitly define the field as `genre` and set the [source](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#source) argument to `genre_type_id` so it maps `genre_type_id` to / from `genre`.

Comment: I suppose I could do it like that:
 `mapping_fields = (('gender', 'genre_type_id'), )`

Comment: Follow this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48162727/how-to-map-to-request-post-json-key-to-model-serialializer-field-in-django