# How to map to request.post json key to model serialializer field in django?

Tags: python, json, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I am newbie in **djnago-rest-framework**. I am leaning about creating instance with serializer in **DRF**.

Let suppose I have models who look like this **(models.py)** :

```
from django.db import models

class Reporter(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    email = models.EmailField()


class Article(models.Model):
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    reporter = models.ForeignKey(Reporter, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

My serializer look like this **(serializers.py)** :

```
Class AricleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    reporter = PkDictField(model_class=Reporter)
    class Meta:
        model = Article
        field = ('headline', 'reporter')
```

If I post the data like this:

```
$ curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"headline":"NewHeadline", "reporter":1}' http://localhost:8000/create-article/
```

In this case everything work fine, It create new entry of article.

But actually I want to rename field **reporter** to **article_reporter**

so actual post request look like this

```
$ curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"headline":"NewHeadline", "article_reporter":1}' http://localhost:8000/create-article/
```

Yes I understand I can rename key "article_reporter" to "reporter" in **views.py** before to send data to serializer and It will work fine.

But I want to handle this in serializer class, **AricleSerialize**. can someone tell me how can I solve this in serializer? Any help would be appreciater.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am face the same problem but I handle this problem using Jquery 
the Serialize return raw (dict of list {[]} ) JSON dataset
please have a look my project in Github [enter link description here](https://github.com/dangerrockstar/django_with_data_table.js) i hope here you can find your problem solution

Answer (score 0):

There will be lot of ways to do that,

1. You can do that by front end javascript or jquery itself.
2. You can map the value in the Custom function like below

   http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/
3. You can write custom serializer function to save that data

   http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/1-serialization/
4. Orelse you can use Model alias name like this

   https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#db-column

Answer (score 0):

You just need to do this in your serializer:

`reporter = models.ForeignKey(Reporter, on_delete=models.CASCADE, source='article_reporter')`

Answer (score 0):

Although this is an old question, I had a similar issue (sans the differing name field being a foreign key) and this is what solved it for me.

- First of all, the values in the `field` attribute of class Meta refer to the API fields and not your model fields.
- You need to set the `source` attribute for the fields (whose request.data key differs from the model field name) to map them to your model fields.
- One of the answers above explicitly declares the reporter field in the serializer but if you do not wish to do that, then a more concise alternative is to specify the `source` attribute using the `extra_kwargs` option of Model Serializer as below:

```
Class AricleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Article
        field = ('headline', 'article_reporter')
        extra_kwargs = {
            "article_reporter": {"source": "reporter"}
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to map incoming post request key value to your field name you have two options:

- the first is with the `source` attribute. That is the most common usage.
- the second is using the `.to_internal_value` method. For some of us the first could be not the solution, because sometimes json keys or values come as data, which python/django does not accept. Integers as variable names, reserved words like `from`, `class` etc. The code below maps `article_reporter` to the model field name `reporter`. The return value is just for the `.validated_data` property and will be `{reporter : 1 }` for instance

```
    class AricleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        reporter = PkDictField(model_class=Reporter)
        class Meta:
            model = Article
            fields = ('headline', 'reporter')

            def to_internal_value(self, data):
                reporter = data.get('article_reporter')
                
                return {
                    'reporter':reporter
                }
```